# Loop through a big JSON object, turn into an array and then turn that array into a JSON, is it possible? (Angular)

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using Dynamo DB and I can't get unique values but I MUST get them.
The thing is, after I get these unique values I have to query them again so I can obtain information.

The result of my first query is something like:  ( btw, this is print from `this.listaSondas` )

```js
{
    NRO_SERIE: "00055",
    HUMEDAD: "45",
    FECHA: "28-02-2017 03:13",
    CO2: "11.5",
    TEMPERATURA: "50",
  }
 {
    NRO_SERIE: "00055",
    HUMEDAD: "45",
    FECHA: "28-02-2017 03:16",
    CO2: "11.5",
    TEMPERATURA: "50",
  }
 {
    NRO_SERIE: "00055",
    HUMEDAD: "15",
    FECHA: "28-02-2017 03:19",
    CO2: "11.5",
    TEMPERATURA: "50",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "00055",
    HUMEDAD: "150",
    FECHA: "28-02-2017 03:41",
    CO2: "11.5",
    TEMPERATURA: "50",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "00055",
    HUMEDAD: "140",
    FECHA: "28-02-2017 03:43",
    CO2: "11.5",
    TEMPERATURA: "50",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "00055",
    HUMEDAD: "130",
    FECHA: "28-02-2017 05:04",
    CO2: "11.5",
    TEMPERATURA: "50",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "0006",
    HUMEDAD: "100",
    FECHA: "07-02-2017 05:24",
    CO2: "8,0",
    TEMPERATURA: "52",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "0006",
    HUMEDAD: "150",
    FECHA: "07-02-2017 05:36",
    CO2: "8,0",
    TEMPERATURA: "80",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "0006",
    HUMEDAD: "94",
    FECHA: "07-08-2016 19:31",
    CO2: "0.9",
    TEMPERATURA: "40",
  }
{
    NRO_SERIE: "0006",
    HUMEDAD: "100",
    FECHA: "07-08-2016 21:06",
    CO2: "99",
    TEMPERATURA: "99",
  }
```

So I loop through them like this:

```js
      for (let sonda = 0; sonda < this.listaSondas.length; sonda++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.listaSondas[sonda].NRO_SERIE.length; i++) {
          let sondaResult = this.listaSondas[sonda].NRO_SERIE;
          if (this.result.indexOf(sondaResult) == '-1') {
            this.result.push(sondaResult)          
          }
        }
      }
```

And this is the result of `this.result` :

```js
["00055", "0006", "00005", "00011", "00001", "0001", "00075", "00010", "0007", "00006", "0002"]
```

Now I have to `POST` that but I have to turn it into a JSON object (It won't work with JSON.stringify).
What should I do?

The JSON format that is working in my postman is the following:

```
{
  "sonda": "00055"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want a little more sophistication surrounding your POST, but this should do it.

```js
const sondas = [
  { NRO_SERIE: "00055" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "00055" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "00055" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "00055" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "00055" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "00055" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "0006" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "0006" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "0006" },
  { NRO_SERIE: "0006" }
].map(obj => ({sonda: obj.NRO_SERIE}));

console.log(sondas);

const url = "someUrl";
sondas.forEach(sonda => {
  $http.post(url, sonda);
});
```

Comment: It has to be in the format because I'll POST that object and receive a response from the server.

Comment: I don't understand. Should `sonda` be a joined string of all the array values? What is the end result?

Comment: Yup, sonda should be joined so I can iterate a query on my server, to do that I have to post a JSON.

Comment: Updated answer^

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain myself well, but I need one JSON object for each number

Comment: Are you going to make a POST for each object?

Comment: Exactly. That's what the client needs

Comment: Updated your loop + added a simple POST.

Comment: that might actually work. But the object creation should be automatic. First I receive an object, iterate through that object, create an array and then from that array I create another object (sondas).